# Master and develop branch analysis in sonarQube (Community Edition)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube community edition which does not support multi-branch analysis. Is there any way to have develop and master branch code displayed under different project reports in sonarqube(i.e 1:sonarqube-develop-code 2:sonarqube-master-code). I want to generate different sonarqube reports (Community Edition) for develop and master branch of java code (maven dependencies) using sonar-scanner plugin through Jenkins. Currently two jenkins jobs are running release(master branch) and develop job (develop branch) so can i add sonarscanner as built step and simply add project.name and project key parameters in sonar analysis column. i cannot change group id and artifact id in pom.xml for each branch so looking for a workaround

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrEb7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer for multi-branch-analysis, sonarqube supports them in developer edition & above. Refer: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/ (Read top)

My thoughts,

You can create two Jenkins pipeline for same repo, just checkout master or develop to scan them using sonar cli.

Using sonar scanner cli helps in overriding the configs as you will not be looking for them in pom.xml. Its faster as it doesn't have to download maven dependencies(if you are builds are happening in containers)
Refer: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/

Comment: You should write the Jenkins pipeline with the sonarcli call in your answer.  In general your answer should have sample code.